# Can you withdraw capital gains from a stock sale and still deduct interest on the original cost basis?

Tags: canada, tax-deduction, interest, margin, canada-revenue-agency

Say you borrow 50k and buy 100k of shares.

Then the stock rises to 100k
You sell half and cancel out the loan, but also have 50k of capital gains.

If you withdraw the 50k gain to maintain the original loan of 50k, to maintain the same leverage ratio on the remaining position, is the interest expense deductible as prior to the withdrawal?